# To get the suggestion about radius authentication using standard PAM and ssh Modules

Tags: radius

We support Radius Authentication in our product (working as a client) by mapping different template user accounts to radius authenticated users. These user accounts are created on radius server.Template user accounts are created on client locally.
We have some specific attributes that are defined in the customized dictionary file on radius server. The code modification for supporting these attributes and mapping the template user accounts (inheriting the privileges, file ownership, and effective user ID  from template accounts) to Radius users has been done in pam_radius and openSSH source code.

We also have customized SSH source code to handle enabling and disabling of radius feature (sending radius request message or not).

Is there any way to remove this customization with the sole purpose of doing 
the radius authentication (having user entries created on radius server) only using the standard PAM module and SSH RPM’s?

We are using IC and SBR radius servers. The pam module  is being used from freeradius.org.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).